# skip the whole loop without running the while

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I have a while loop and I want to skip the whole loop without running the condition in parantheses again becuse as you now, the vector's Size is one greater then their cell number. I mean it is like:

```
[ Cell 0 ][ Cell 1 ][ Cell 2] --> Size = 3
```

So I have to skip the whole loop to prevent an Error. I need to write something that takes the program from point A to B without running "while()" My loop:

```cpp
    size = 0;
    while ((usernamelog[size] != usrlog || passwordlog[size] != passlog) && size < usernamelog.size())//Checking Username And Password
    {
        if (x == 2)//Login Unsuccessfull
           cout << "Username or Password is Incorrect. Please try again." << endl;
        cout << "Enter Your Username: ";
        cin >> usrlog;
        cout << "Enter Your Password: ";
        cin >> passlog;
        x = 2;
        size++;
        if (usernamelog.size() == size)
           //Point A
    }

    //Point B
```

for example, when usernamelog.size is 2 and size is 2, Jump From A to B

Comment: Are you looking for `break;`?

Comment: Think about the *order* of your comparisions in the condition. And think about how the [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) nature of the logical operators dictates the order in which conditions are evaluated.

Comment: And think about how you can use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: no. break doesn't work. still runs the while loop and causes an error. I am Using VS 2015

Comment: Maybe you wanna move the part with `size < usernamelog.size()` in front of the accessors `usernamelog[size] != usrlog || passwordlog[size] != passlog`

Comment: And to directly answer your question about how to get from "Point A" to "Point B", that is what the `break` statement does. You don't need it if you fix the loop condition, but that's how to *break* out of a loop immediately.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no it doesn't break out of the loop. first goes to the beginning of the loop, checks the condition and outputs an error because there is no element 2 in a vector with size 2

Comment: Don't you want something like: `auto credential = AskCredential(); while (!loginMgr.IsValid(credential)) {DisplayInvalidCredentialMessage(); credential = AskCredential();} }` [Demo](https://ideone.com/8htwPA).

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. If you put a `break` where you have the comment `//Point A` it should should break out of the loop immediately when the condition `if (usernamelog.size() == size)` is true, and never index out of bounds.

Comment: No @Jarod42. I have to use it like this. I am not allowed to use any external code except cout, cin and while loop.

Comment: But a better solution (IMO) would be to have a loop like `for (size_t size = 0; size < usernamelog.size() && ((usernamelog[size] != usrlog || passwordlog[size] != passlog)); ++size) { ... }` and then skip the `if (usernamelog.size() == size)` check (as well as the `size++;` statement inside the loop).

Comment: *"I have to use it like this"* What do you mean? you can only add code in `PointA`? My point was not to use `<vector>` or `<algorithm>` but to change the logic to validate credential (which seems to be what you want, even if code currently seems to expect several validations).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) :

> After this statement the control is transferred to the statement immediately following the enclosing loop or switch. As with any block exit, all automatic storage objects declared in enclosing compound statement or in the condition of a loop/switch are destroyed, in reverse order of construction, before the execution of the first line following the enclosing loop.

Example:

```
while (true) { 
    std::cout << "this loop runs only once";
    break;
}
```

There is an "issue" that comes up sometimes when you have nested loops, so I'll also add it here even not relevant for your code at the moment. Note that `break` only breaks out of the most inner loop. Once you have more loops you need more than a single `break`. For example this will run till infinity:

```
while (true) {
    while (true) {
        break;
    }
}
```

An easy solution is to put the loops inside a function and to `return`:

```
void foo() {
    while (true) {
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "this will be printed only once";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can do this also for a single loop and often that is the cleaner way.

PS: If you do know the number of iterations beforehand, then it is more idomatic to use a for loop instead. Also consider to fix your conditions such that you do not need to break out of the loop from within the body.

Comment: A better solution is to write better conditions.

Comment: no it doesn't work. it will run the while condition between parantheses and it will cause an error.  I am using VS 2015

Comment: @Caleb added a note on that

Comment: @ParsaShowkati what do you mean? what is "it" and how does it not work? What is the error?

Comment: when you try to read a data from cell 2 of a vector when the vector size is 2, do you think it works?

Comment: @ParsaShowkati sorry no idea what you are talking about. There is no cell 2 in my examples and in your code you have a condition to prevent this from happening, no? You just need to break if the condition is `true`.